# Do loop with step size being being a doubling factor

Tags: procedural-programming

Right now I'm doing loops like this:

`For[n=10, n<1000, n =2n, Do Stuff]`. Is there a way to do this as a `Do[]` loop? I know you can do steps in `Do[]` loops, but don't know how to do steps where it isn't just i+=1.

Comment: You can do constant step sizes != 1. e.g. `Do[something,{n,10,1000,2}]` will count by 2, (10,12,14...), but you'll have to use a similar syntax as goerge2079 suggests to get a more complicated behavior. Although there is probably something better than a loop to do almost anything you're trying to do.

Comment: `Do[n = 10 2^i; do stuff , {i, 6}]`  If you don't want to (or can't) determine the formula like that, I'd prefer `While` over `For` (perhaps a matter of taste). `n = 5; While[(n *= 2 ) < 1000, do stuff];`

Comment: Another possibility is to define a list `list` of the values of `n` you want, and then `Table[ do stuff, {i,list}]` (but then it's not a `Do` loop of course).

Comment: `Do[ Print[n] , {n, NestWhileList[2*# &, 10, # < 1000 &]}]`

Answer (score 2):

This is documented (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html). Look at the fifth form.

```
Do[< Do stuff >, {n, Table[10 2^i, {i, 0, 6}]}]
```

Answer (score -2):

Your stuff, I presume, needs an index,hopping freely in the integers.

Prepare your index list as

list = Array[ (myspecialhopperN[#]]&, {10000}]

and do your stuff by

Fold[stuff[#2]&,dummy,list]

As we all know, decision making in loops is more costly than doing math.